# Difference between linux packages python-requests and python2-requests

Tags: rpm, rhel8, almalinux

I am trying to install python-requests rpm on almalinux 8 os. But there is no package available for el8 for python-requests.
There is an alternative available "python2-requests". Can I go ahead with installing python2-requets and make the relevant changes for required package in my rpm or are there any major differences between the 2.

Answer (score 0):

`python-requests` is the source package (src.rpm). `python2-requests` is the resulting package with python2 library. This is to differentiate from resulting package with python3 library `python3-requests`. If package is well designed then the same `python-requests.src.rpm` produces `python2-requests.rpm` for el8 systems and `python3-requests.rpm` for el9 systems.